# How save BitmapImage WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I have BitmapImage:

```
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
image.SetSource(memStream);
```

I want to save the image to the disk to see in the future. I can not find a work example of how to do this? The second question. I need to get the color of a pixel (like: `Color cl=image.GetColorPixel(X,Y)`), how can I do that?
Thank you!

Comment: Pls consider marking a post as a solution or point out what you finally did

Answer (score 4):

Here's a code I found sometime ago in the web. I'm not sure, but if I rember right it was from the sdk samples or a winrt blog

It all comes down to the WritabelBitmap Image ( like the other already posted), create a decoder and push it to the stream.

```
  /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="writeableBitmap"></param>
        /// <param name="outputFile"></param>
        /// <param name="encoderId"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static async Task SaveToFile(
            this WriteableBitmap writeableBitmap,
            IStorageFile outputFile,
            Guid encoderId)
        {
            try
            {
                Stream stream = writeableBitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream();
                byte[] pixels = new byte[(uint)stream.Length];
                await stream.ReadAsync(pixels, 0, pixels.Length);

                using (var writeStream = await outputFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
                {
                    var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(encoderId, writeStream);
                    encoder.SetPixelData(
                        BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
                        BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied,
                        (uint)writeableBitmap.PixelWidth,
                        (uint)writeableBitmap.PixelHeight,
                        96,
                        96,
                        pixels);
                    await encoder.FlushAsync();

                    using (var outputStream = writeStream.GetOutputStreamAt(0))
                    {
                        await outputStream.FlushAsync();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string s = ex.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can save BitmapImage in the following way.

```
Windows.Storage.StorageFolder localFolder =   Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        StorageFile sampleFile = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("image.png");
        await FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(sampleFile, bytes);
```

image.png will be saved  in the LocalFolder of the Application.

Hope it helps!

- Binaya Raj Shrestha

Answer (score 1):

You can't save or modify a `BitmapImage`. You need to use a `WriteableBitmap` instead. If you really have no choice but start with a BitmapImage - check its `UriSource` property to either download the same image again or load a `WriteableBitmap` with same content as the starting `BitmapImage`. Note that `UriSource` might be null in some cases - even if the `BitmapImage` was loaded by giving it a URI - it might be reset manually or by [setting `CacheMode` to `BitmapCache` on an `Image` that's using the given `BitmapImage` as its `Source`](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/f2a2348d-49b5-404c-b932-dc60ffd5828a).

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this link. there's a snippet showing some manipulation of WriteableBitmap
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx

The example is reading but writing shouldn't be difficult.

To iterate through the pixels, have a look at PixelData Property.

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to take a ui element from your xaml and save it as an image your out of luck.  In wpf there is a method on writable bitmap that takes a UIelement as a parameter but that isn't there in windows store apps.

You can use DirectX but this is a very complicated approach.  Most of the drawing apps on the store use JavaScript as its much easier to do the save.