# How to save manipulated images in windows 8 store app c#?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

XAML Code:

```
<Image x:Name="layer1Image" ImageOpened="layer1Image_Opened"
                ManipulationMode="All"
                ManipulationDelta="layer1Image_ManipulationDelta">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform x:Name="layer1ImageTransform"></CompositeTransform>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>


private void layer1Image_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
                var currentImage = e.OriginalSource as Image;
    var transform = currentImage.RenderTransform as CompositeTransform;

    transform.TranslateX += e.Delta.Translation.X;
    transform.TranslateY += e.Delta.Translation.Y;

    transform.ScaleX *= e.Delta.Scale;
    transform.ScaleY *= e.Delta.Scale;

    transform.Rotation += e.Delta.Rotation;
}
```

I have performed scaling, rotation and move an image, how can i save my manipulated image in local machine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How save BitmapImage WinRT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15494965/how-save-bitmapimage-winrt)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you cant save a manipulated image
[link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4f9567b1-439e-4aac-ae59-8baf52f9b601/rotate-and-save-image)

This is what you are looking for
[link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/521bfdcf-b812-43d3-b433-00c09a7b1b28/wpf-rotate-image)