# Any way to save a resized BitmapImage in WP 8.1

Tags: image, windows-phone-8.1, image-resizing, bitmapimage

How can I save a resized BitmapImage? I can't find the way to do this in Windows Phone 8.1   Here is my code:

```
BitmapImage bitm = new BitmapImage();
await bitm.SetSourceAsync(stream);

bitm.DecodePixelWidth = 200;
bitm.DecodePixelHeight = 250;

myImage.ImageSource= bitm;
```

(Now I want to store in a file because the saved image is too big)

Comment: What format do you want jpeg, png or ?

Comment: Any format is valid.

Comment: Then the answer given should suffice, if the image is already locally stored :)

Comment: No, because the stored image is too big(20mb), and I want to replace it with a small resized image, but I don't find nothing about how to save a Bitmap in Wp 8.1

Comment: Based on your comment on the answer then you could look at the nuget package `Cimbalino` it extens the writeablebitmap with `savepng`. I think this also works for win-rt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use WriteableBitmap for saving the image.

```
    private async void SaveImage(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BitmapImage bitm = new BitmapImage();
        await bitm.SetSourceAsync(stream);
        bitm.DecodePixelWidth = 200;
        bitm.DecodePixelHeight = 250;
        WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitm);
        wb.Invalidate();
        using (IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream imageStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("/Shared/ShellContent/hello.jpg", System.IO.FileMode.Create, isf))
            {
                wb.SaveJpeg(imageStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: The problem is that my app is a wp 8.1, not silverlight, so this not work because WriteableBitmap don't have a .ScaveJpeg method or constructor with bitmapImage parameter

Comment: Then you can check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15494965/how-save-bitmapimage-winrt