# Xamarin forms UWP: how can I save an jpg from ImageSource?

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp

I can save a picture in iOS and Android but I can't find a way to save an image in UWP. Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any code? What does the iOS and Android code look like?

Comment: For iOS and Android it's working fine. In UWP doesn't work, some tutorial on line are wrong or incomplete. I can share my code.

Comment: Please do share some code, maybe it gives me some hint about your requirements and how you solved it in iOS and Android. Please update your question with the code and/or the tutorial you are following

Comment: As I know, if you want to save files, you will need to get stream /byte array from the original source, but `ImageSource` of xamarin has no such method, we need to keep reference to the original source. So how you did in IOS and Android? What is your image source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't find a way to save an image in UWP

No, we can't extract the image data from an Xamarin [`ImageSource`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource/) object.

There is `StreamImagesourceHandler` class implementation in UWP, see [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinRT/StreamImagesourceHandler.cs#L17)

```
public sealed class StreamImageSourceHandler : IImageSourceHandler
{
    public async Task<Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.ImageSource> LoadImageAsync(ImageSource imagesource, CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {
        BitmapImage bitmapimage = null;

        //Omitted

        return bitmapimage;
    }
}
```

So we need to extract data from [`BitmapImage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapimage.aspx).

Actually the `BitmapImage` class is inherited from [`ImageSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.imagesource.aspx) class, while we can't extract the image data from `ImageSource`, for the reason, please see these two questions:

- [Convert ImageSource to WriteableBitmap in Metro Windows 8](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c059b1f9-8a28-47c2-a259-3ab561c6e49a)
- [How save BitmapImage WinRT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15494965/how-save-bitmapimage-winrt)

---

The solution here is to use different way for Windows Runtime(W/WP8.1 & UWP) app, extracting image data from `System.IO.Stream` class is supported in UWP.

We can use `DependencyService` to access native platform features, firstly, create an interface in PCL:

```
public interface ISaveImage
{
    void SavePictureToDisk(ImageSource imgSrc, string Id, bool OverwriteIfExist = false);
    void SavePictureToDiskWINRT(System.IO.Stream imgStream, string Id, bool OverwriteIfExist = false);
}
```

In the code behind of Xamarin page:

```
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String("iVBOxxxxxxxxxxMVEX/uQOAuwPzUxxxxxxxxxxxx="));
    ImageSource imgsource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => memoryStream);

    if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Windows|| Device.OS == TargetPlatform.WinPhone)
         DependencyService.Get<ISaveImage>().SavePictureToDiskWINRT(memoryStream, "1");
    else
         DependencyService.Get<ISaveImage>().SavePictureToDisk(imgsource, "1");
```

Implement the interface in UWP platform:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using WorkingWithImages.WinUniversal;
using System.IO;
using System;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;

[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(SaveImageImplementation))]
namespace WorkingWithImages.WinUniversal
{
    public class SaveImageImplementation : ISaveImage
    {
        public SaveImageImplementation() { }

        public void SavePictureToDisk(ImageSource imgSrc, string Id, bool OverwriteIfExist = false)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public async void SavePictureToDiskWINRT(Stream imgStream, string Id, bool OverwriteIfExist = false)
        {
            var inStream = imgStream.AsRandomAccessStream();
            var fileBytes = new byte[inStream.Size];
            using (DataReader reader = new DataReader(inStream))
            {
                await reader.LoadAsync((uint)inStream.Size);
                reader.ReadBytes(fileBytes);
            }

            var file = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(Id+".jpg", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            using (var fs = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
            {
                var outStream = fs.GetOutputStreamAt(0);
                var dataWriter = new DataWriter(outStream);
                dataWriter.WriteBytes(fileBytes);
                await dataWriter.StoreAsync();
                dataWriter.DetachStream();
                await outStream.FlushAsync();
                outStream.Dispose();
                fs.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Please check my completed demo in [here](https://github.com/Myfreedom614/UWP-Samples/tree/master/WorkingWithImages)**

About UWP File storage guidance, please see [Create, write, and read a file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files)

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

maybe someone needs a solution for iOS and Android (below). Meanwhile I'm waiting an idea for UWP.

## iOS

```
     /// <summary>
    /// Saves the picture to disk.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The picture to disk.</returns>
    /// <param name="imgSrc">Image source.</param>
    /// <param name="id">Identifier.</param>
    /// <param name="overwriteIfExist">if set to <c>true</c> overwrite if exist.</param>
    /// <returns>The picture to disk.</returns>
    public async void SaveImage(ImageSource imgSrc, string id, bool overwriteIfExist = false)
    {
        var renderer = new StreamImagesourceHandler();
        var photo = await renderer.LoadImageAsync(imgSrc);

        string jpgFilename = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), id + ".jpg");

        if (File.Exists(jpgFilename))
        {
            File.Delete(jpgFilename);
        }

        NSData imgData = photo.AsJPEG();
        NSError err;
        if (imgData.Save(jpgFilename, false, out err))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("saved as " + jpgFilename);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("NOT saved as " + jpgFilename
                                + " because" + err.LocalizedDescription);
        }

    }
```

Good to know, when iOS saves an image as *jpg*, the image header says *png*.

## Android

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Saves the picture to disk.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="imgSrc">Image source.</param>
    /// <param name="id">The image identifier.</param>
    /// <param name="overwriteIfExist">if set to <c>true</c> overwrite if exist.</param>
    /// <returns>The picture to disk.</returns>
    public async void SaveImage(ImageSource imgSrc, string id,
                                        bool overwriteIfExist = false)
    {
        var renderer = new StreamImagesourceHandler();
        var photo = await renderer.LoadImageAsync(imgSrc, Forms.Context);

        string jpgFilename = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), id + ".jpg");

        if (File.Exists(jpgFilename))
        {
            File.Delete(jpgFilename);
        }

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(jpgFilename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            photo.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, fs);
        }
     }
```